# Why does my name appear in the list of duplicate voters when I didn't vote for that?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Today there had been a close voting for [Latex users make more mistakes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489259/latex-users-make-more-mistakes) which finally lead to the question being closed as a duplicate. After a more careful re-examination of the close proposal, the exact duplicate vote seems to be correct.

I took part in this close voting but unfortunately didn't pay close attention (no pun intended), as I just read the topic of the duplicate question and *did* vote to close, but as "offtopic - should be migrated to the tex.meta site."

However, I still occur in the list of duplicate voters, although I've never voted to close this question as duplicate.

Does that mean, a question will always be closed, no matter how many people vote for the different close reasons, as long as the *total* close votes sum up to five? Also, what close reason will be the final one in that case, the one that got the first vote, the one with the most votes etc.?

Comment: This is how the whole system works.  Not everyone is happy about it, but I don't think it will change. See [Distinguish close votes by reason](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917) for discussion on the main Meta site.

Comment: I just can say that I am also very unhappy about this. Which is why I became very reluctant to cast close votes. But I believe this defeats the purpose since we clearly need to weed out not completely appropriate questions. Similar comments apply to the gold badge thingy, which essentially prevent me from casting close votes on questions on topics which I am most familiar with simply because I do not want to close them singlehandedly.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for the link. I was always under the impression, that five votes per reason are necessary to close a question. Apparently, this assumption was wrong. So I will just skip close votes in the future if I don't agree with the reasons people have already voted for.

Comment: Most close vote categories automatically add comments, e.g., duplicate votes always add a comment with a link to the duplicate question. So if you vote to close a question with another reason than the already done votes others can at least see your real reason for the close vote. Indeed I would also prefer if each category would be counted independent. On the other hand in such a case everyone should also be able to change his vote from one category to another.

Comment: [This is another example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/492286/156344). Raaja said "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a just-do-it-for-me question." but the result is "marked as duplicate by Raaja, Stefan Pinnow, ...".